# Android Layout Structuring

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-imageview

I want to create a layout like below..

[image]

This is the XML i have come across

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/display_photo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/username"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Username"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timestamp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="2 hours ago"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/location"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Location"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

How can i have the text over with .... after certain characters.. and how to place the time on the right handside ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve that kind of Layout you better use Relative Layout which will be rendered properly amongst any devices.Something like this should be okay.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="center"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="#FFFFFF">   
<ImageView android:layout_height="100px" android:id="@+id/deal_image"
    android:layout_width="120px" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></ImageView>
<TextView android:id="@+id/deal_description"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/deal_image" android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:padding="2dp" android:textColor="#000000" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/deal_time" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="120px" android:padding="2dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/deal_image" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="#13ADDF" android:textSize="12dip"></TextView>

<TextView android:id="@+id/real_price" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="120px" android:padding="2dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/deal_time" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="#13ADDF" android:textSize="12dip"></TextView>
<TextView android:id="@+id/deal_price" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:padding="2dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/real_price"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/buy_button" android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#13ADDF" android:textSize="15dip"
    android:layout_below="@id/deal_description" android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_alignBottom="@id/buy_button"></TextView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

You can edit this and can achieve the structure that you want to display pretty much easily.

Comment: sorry. guess i didnt ask the question properly. i need help with achieving that layout.

Comment: ah i see if that's the case then you need to use a relative layout which is much more appropriate for positioning the objects.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of layouts, the best is to use the simple LinearLayout with a horitzontal direction, and the two textView with the information.

To have the dots (...) you have to set the [ellipsize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aellipsize) and to make the name textview of the name fill all the available space use the weight attribute. The nameText have a layout_weight=1 and the timeText a layout_weight=0.

Hope it help :)

Comment: i added that.. but doesnt help.. may be i still need to structure the app in a way to get that effective

Answer (score 0):

Please find below code may be helpful for you

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:background="@drawable/main_prf"></ImageView>
                <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_centerVertical="true">
                    <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2">
                        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView4" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></TextView>
                        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView4" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></TextView>
                    </RelativeLayout>
                    <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
                    <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

[image: layout file]

Comment: gratz you just add 3 unnecessary layouts http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-efficiency.html